# Prove this inequality $x^{1-x\ }+\log \left(1-x\right)\ +2^{x\ }+\left(1-x\right)^x+\log \left(x\right)+2^{\left(1-x\right)}<3.7$

Tags: inequality

Prove this inequality $x^{1-x\ }+\log \left(1-x\right)\ +2^{x\ }+\left(1-x\right)^x+\log \left(x\right)+2^{\left(1-x\right)}<3.7$

I came up with this on my own and checked this using Desmos. Will edit in my attempts after a few days.

**My Thoughts**

1. Differentiating the function. This is bound to give us an answer. But the main problem I feel here is that it will be difficult to get a analytic solution. This method will also take up time and is pretty cumbersome.
2. This is what I'm specifically looking for, *a non calculus solution!*

Comment: What does the derivative tell you?  This function is symmetric about $x=\frac{1}{2}$ (and only defined in $[0,1]$).

Comment: @Michael Burr...It is not defined at 1..

Comment: @user35508. The main point is the symmetry pointed out by Michael Burr; from this we can immediately conclude. I wonder why $3.7$ and not less.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Pls can you give your method in a answer. Thanks:)

Comment: Michael Burr gave already the answer. The maximum of the function is at $x=\frac 12$. Plug it in the lhs to get a maximum value $3 \sqrt{2}-2\log (2)\approx 2.85635$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Symmetry alone does not guarantee that the maximum is attained at the midpoint (unless you have concavity as well, which is not obvious to me). – Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR. I totally agree with you. Just checking the value of the derivative was sufficient I think. Again, all credit is for Michael Burr.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I am not sure what we agree about :) – It is clear that $f$ is symmetric about $x=1/2$, so $f'(1/2) = 0$. It is not clear (to me) that $f'(x) = 0$ has no other solutions, i.e. that there are no extremal points beside $x=1/2$

Comment: @user35508 Right, and not at $0$ either, so I meant $(0,1)$.